# How to populate a BulletedList with text+LinkButton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bulletedlist

I have this code that I use to populate a BulletedList in my page with the current roles in the site + some extra information.

So far, since all these are text-related, no problem.

Now I would like to have a LinkButton control at the end of the role string which if pressed it will delete the role (and repopulate the list) (like the functionality that the admin tool in visual studio has)

My question is: Is there a way to do that in a bulleted list, or should I use another control (like a gridview)?

```
private void BindRolesToList()
    {
        string[] roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
        string[] data = new string[Roles.GetAllRoles().Count()];

        for (int i = 0; i<roles.Length; i++ )
        {
            data[i] = "Role name: " + roles[i] + ". Number of members in the role: " + Roles.GetUsersInRole(roles[i]).Count() + ".";
        }

        RoleList.DataSource = data;
        RoleList.DataBind();    
    }
```

Comment: What does the aspx file which goes with that look like?

Comment: What do you mean? I just draged and dropped a bulleted list in the page and wrote this method on the code behind. Then i inlcude it in the page_load. The project is not a MVC if that makes any difference.

Comment: Ah, okay. I don't know about how to do asp.net pages using the drag-n-drop editor... (When you save the file, it should write out some HTML-looking stuff, which is what I typically work with. Examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.aspx#exampleToggle )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into it some more:

Short answer: No, adding another control inside a `BulletedList` is not possible. `BulletedList`s do not support templating.

If you want the whole role string to be a `HyperLink` or a `LinkButton`, you can simply set the [`DisplayMode` of the `BulletedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.displaymode.aspx).

If you want the LinkButton to appear at the end of the text string, you need to use a more flexible list structure. [`Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) is probably the easiest to get the effect you are describing.

---

Something like

```
   <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <HeaderTemplate>
         <ul>
      </HeaderTemplate>

      <ItemTemplate>
         <li>Role name: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RoleName") %>. 
             Number of members in the role: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RoleCount") %>. 
             <asp:LinkButton onCommand="LinkButton_Command" 
                 CommandArgument="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RoleName") %>"
                 />
         </li>
      </ItemTemplate>

      <FooterTemplate>
         </ul>
      </FooterTemplate>

   </asp:Repeater>
```

with code-behind

```
private void BindRolesToList()
{
    string[] roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();

    //make a table for the data, with two columns, RoleName and RoleCount
    DataTable data = new DataTable();

    DataColumn column;

    column = New DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    column.ColumnName = "RoleName";
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    column = New DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    column.ColumnName = "RoleCount";
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    // Populate the data
    DataRow row;
    for (int i = 0; i<roles.Length; i++ )
    {
         row = data.NewRow();
         row["RoleName"] = roles[i];
         row["RoleCount"] = Roles.GetUsersInRole(roles[i]).Count();
         data.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    RoleList.DataSource = data;
    RoleList.DataBind();    
}

private void LinkButton_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
    string RoleName = e.CommandArgument;

    //whatever code deletes the role, e.g.
    //  Roles.DeleteRole(RoleName);

    BindRolesToList();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into it! I was researching the Repeater class all this time also but i haven't grasp the whole binding thing yet to be honest... I saw an example with binding an object to a repeater and thought of trying to make a class that has as parameters a string (the first part) and a LinkButton and then bind an array of them on the repeater!! The code you posted is full of information that is definetly needed. Thanks again.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can also declare the `<ul> </ul>` wrapper outside of the `<asp:repeater>` code instead of including it as a header/footer template item.

Comment: @TylerH You can. If I remember correctly, it results in a slightly different outcome if the list is empty - if there are no rows, the header and footer template items should be dropped, but if you wrap the `<ul>` tags around the outside of the `<asp:repeater>`, then an empty list will result in an empty `<ul></ul>` block. Depending on your desired outcome, you can use the appropriate arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add the linkbutton at the end of each row, using which user can delete the record.

For this you can add the linkbutton in datagridview and on click event of that linkbutton you can delete that specefic row.

You can do the same thing even in Repeater instead of datagridview.