# How to dynamically add items to bulleted list from code-behind in the master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

My master page has a bulleted list defined as below:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnHome" runat="server" class="active" CausesValidation="false">Home </asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:BulletedList ID="headerMenu" DisplayMode="LinkButton" class="nav navbar-nav" CausesValidation="false" runat="server">
            </asp:BulletedList>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to access it from a content page (child of master) "_Default.cs" and add some items to it. Below is what I have already tried but it doesn't work as I'm getting error ***'System.Web.UI.WebControls.BulletedList' does not allow child controls.***

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            LinkButton mybl = new LinkButton();
            mybl.Text = "my item";
            BulletedList Bl = (BulletedList)Master.FindControl("headerMenu");
            if (Bl != null) {
                Bl.Controls.Add(mybl);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

How can I change the master page dynamically and modify the BulletedList from my child content page?

Comment: I don't think you can add `LinkButton` inside `BulletedList` like that, because `BulletedList` doesn't support templating. Just use `DisplayMode="LinkButton"` and use `Click` event to trigger postback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate a BulletedList with text+LinkButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847357/how-to-populate-a-bulletedlist-with-textlinkbutton)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I have updated the details of the bulleted list. Basically what if I just want to add a text? For now I just want to be able to modify it.

Comment: Simply use `headerMenu.Items.Add("my item");`, no need to use `FindControl` if `headerMenu` exists in same masterpage.

Comment: Thanks so much. Being a noob at ASP.net simple things often take me forever to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*BulletedList does not allow child controls* occurred because `BulletedList` doesn't support template controls which usually set with `Controls.Add()` method. Here is a remark from [`BulletedList.Controls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.controls?view=netframework-4.7.2) property:

> The `Controls` property is inherited from the `Control` class and is not
>   applicable to the `BulletedList` control.

Instead, you need to add `ListItem` items into `ListItemCollection` using [`Items.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_ListControl_Items) method, assumed the `BulletedList` exists inside master page:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    headerMenu.Items.Add(new ListItem("my item"));
}
```

If you want item text together with URL, put the URL as second parameter of `ListItem`:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    headerMenu.Items.Add(new ListItem("my item", "http://path/to/url"));
}
```

Reference: [BulletedList Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist?view=netframework-4.7.2)